# Regular expression matching http or www

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to check if the URL sent is beginning with http or www, the following regexp always return true.

```
function checkFormat(url){
    var validUrl='';
    const regExp= new RegExp(/^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/);
    if(regExp.test(url)){
        validUrl= url;
    }
    else{
        validUrl= 'http://'+url;
    }
    console.log(validUrl);
    return validUrl;
}
```

For exemple, if i send test.com, validUrl will be test.com.
If I send http://test.com, validUrl will be http://test.com.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: so validUrl will be the same as the input you give to it?

Comment: BTW, `'www'` is not a protocol, it was a common prefix for domain webpages, but it is quite obsolete and even discouraged. And nothing special happens for an url starting with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally wouldn't use a regular expression here, it's unnecessary.

```
if ( url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("www" ) {
```

will work fine (as long as you've got a polyfill for .startsWith). For adding it on, do

```
const validUrl = url.startsWith("http://") ? url : `http://${url}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression in your example is more complex than you need to simply ascertain whether a valid protocol is present. A more simple expression should suffice:

```
if (!/^http(s?):\/\//.test(url)) {
   url = 'http://' + url;
}
```

If you need to validate overall structure (e.g. a valid suffix must be present), then you should do that separately as currently that would result in an unintended `'http://'` being appended, if for example `'.com'` was missing.